# Build multiple android apk with differnt setting with one project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have three android app projects which has all the same codes except different logos, app icon and different page titles. I was wondering if its possible to make one project and have some kind of build setting that can be used to build three different apps ?

Currently if I update a class file I would have to update in all of the remaining projects manually. I would love to have a way to just update once. How to overcome this problem? Thanks!!

Comment: yes it is possible http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Gradle_Build_Variants_Example and http://blog.brainattica.com/how-to-work-with-flavours-on-android/ and https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/testing-android-product-flavors-with-robolectric/